# CSS prefix scope affecting all same-start-name-styles

Tags: html, css, styles

?is it possible to define a name for style affecting all html elements starting with the same prefix
please do not diverge to classes or tags...
please no SASS, LESS or similar processors
please be aware the question is in defining the style, not filtering with a selector

something like this (the asterisk* thing would work as a wildcard) ->

```
in CSS <style> section
#prfxStyle1* { background-color: #ABCDEF; }

in <HTML> section
<div id="prfxStyle1Metals"> ... </div>
<div id="prfxStyle1Plastics"> ... </div>
<div id="prfxStyle1Organics"> ... </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

The "starts with" selector work for attribute selectors only.

So, in this case, to find the id's starting with *prfxStyle1* you'd do:

```
[id^="prfxStyle1"] {
    /* styles */
}
```

By attribute selectors, you can target to any inline element defined attribute (including custom ones):

```
<div attribute="value">
```

Possible attribute selectors: (From [**MDN docs**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors))

> **[attr]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr.
>   **[attr=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is exactly "value".
>   **[attr~=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr whose value is a whitespace-separated list of words, one of which is exactly "value".
>   **[attr|=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr. Its value can be exactly “value” or can begin with “value” immediately followed by “-” (U+002D). It can be used for language subcode matches.
>   **[attr^=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is prefixed by "value".
>   **[attr$=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value is suffixed by "value".
>   **[attr*=value]**
>   Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and whose value contains at least one occurrence of string "value" as substring.

Comment: I did not know you could do that +1, can you clarify what you mean by `attribute selectors` only, do you just mean not by tag name or type. Only by class and id?

Comment: my question is defining the style phase, not in the selection phase... thanks,,,

Comment: @ZEE - what you mean? Just set the style inside the selector: `[id^="prfxStyle1"] { background-color: #ABCDEF; }`

Comment: @DavidT - Any attributes of the element, even custom ones... See updated answer.

Comment: @LcSalazar, yeah thanks I saw the updates arriving just as I posted my comment. The MDN docs info is very useful.

Comment: thanks any way for your answers man... it's fine to know other opinions,,,

Answer (score 0):

You can add more classes or id's(even it is not very used way) just separating them with a space:

```
<div id="prfxStyle1 Metals"> ... </div>
<div id="prfxStyle1 Plastics"> ... </div>
<div id="prfxStyle1 Organics"> ... </div>
```

And in CSS:

```
#prfxStyle1 {
    //some CSS that will affect all divs
}

#Metals {
    //CSS that will affect just the div with the Metal id
}

#Plastics {
    //CSS that will affect just the div with the Plastics id
}

#Organics {
    //CSS that will affect just the div with the Organics id
}
```

Comment: That is what I'm trying to optimize... I just want to define one style, but define a auto-intelligent apply to several element ID's... in this case a style named #xxx* should apply 'automagically' to elements with id 'xxxMetal', 'xxxPlastic', 'xxxOrganic'... thanks